# Color issue when saving PDF page Pixmap as PNG using PyMuPDF

Tags: pdf, cmyk, pixmap, pymupdf

I'm running the following bit of Python code from the PyMuPDF 1.16.17 documentation, which save PNG images for every page in a PDF file.

```
import sys, fitz  # import the binding
fname = "test.pdf" # get filename from command line
doc = fitz.open(fname)  # open document
for page in doc:  # iterate through the pages
    pix = page.getPixmap()
    pix.writePNG("F:/cynthia/page-%i.png" % page.number)  # store image as a PNG
```

The resulting PNG images' colors are off from the PDF originals (too saturated and high contrast). I know function `Page.getPixmap()` has a "colorspace" argument, and using `Document.getPageImageList` I found out that my PDF's colorspace is "DeviceCMYK". But when I try to get a Pixmap using CMYK as colorspace (replacing the `pix = page.getPixmap()` line with `pix = page.getPixmap(colorspace="CMYK")` or `pix = page.getPixmap(colorspace=csCMYK)), it doesn't change the resulting colors. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please upgrade your PyMuPDF version. Then ICC color support will be included which should improve your output.

Comment: I have used latest package PyMuPDF==1.18.19 still I am getting same error which is reported in this question

Comment: @Leandro Nogueira Couto Is that resolved your issue?

Comment: If you want to save a CMYK pixmap as a PNG, then you must convert it: PNG only supports gray and RGB.

Comment: Pixmap conversion happens like this: ``newpix = fitz.Pixmap(fitz.csRGB, oldpix)``. Or save it as it is, but then you must either use one of the CMYK image support **output** formats, or use method ``pix.pil_save(...)`` which allows saving via Pillow.
What I am confused about: if you want an image of the page, you can freely choose your colorspace - so just take RGB.
If you however want to **extract** an image shown by the page, **only then** you are faced with the issue described above.
But please join the issues or discussions blog of the PyMuPDF home page for this.